# How to send a local image instead of URL to Microsoft Cognitive Face API (analyse an image) using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure-cognitive-services

How to send a local image instead of URL to Microsoft Cognitive Face API (analyse an image) using Python?
What to write in **[binary data]** body to get a emotions of the image stored in the computer. please provide the full code.

[Here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236)'s the website which i am trying

This is what I tried:

```
url = "localhost:5000/";
data=open("C:/Users/Robot 2/Desktop/images/abc.bmp","rb") 
requests.post(url,data=data) 
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: please provide the full code - that you've already tried yourself to solve this.  Read [ask].

Comment: url = "http://localhost:5000/"
data=open("C:/Users/Robot 2/Desktop/images/abc.bmp","rb")
requests.post(url,data=data)
response = requests.post(url, data=data)

i tried this in the body section

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
faceapi_headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'YourKey',
}
faceapi_params = urllib.urlencode({
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,glasses',
})

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
f = open(filename, "rb")
faceapi_body = f.read()
f.close()
conn.request("POST", "/face/v1.0/detect?%s" % faceapi_params, faceapi_body, faceapi_headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
```